# Problem with TikZ and pause/onlside in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pause

i have some problems with tikz and pause in beamer. The graphic crashes every time after the second frame. I have already tried onslide, pasue and only.
Without pause etc. the TikZ picture works...

Can anyone help me here?

best regards
Alex

Sorry for the chaotic code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
    % Define block styles
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}% für Ellipse
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    pfeil/.style={stealth-},
    beschr/.style={remember picture,overlay,font=\small}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, 
    text width=3cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.1cm]
    
    \tikzstyle{block1} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!10, 
    text width=3.2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.1cm]
    \tikzstyle{block2} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!20, 
    text width=3.2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.1cm]
        \tikzstyle{block3} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!25, 
    text width=3.4cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.1cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\centering
{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.4cm, auto]
\footnotesize
    % Place nodes
    \only<1>{
    \node [block] (Messdaten) {\textbf{Start:  ..}};
}
    \only<1-2>{
    \node [block1, right =of  Messdaten] (Maxima) {Unterteilung...};        \path [line] (Messdaten.east) -- (Maxima);
}
    \only<1-3>{
    \node [block2, right =of  Maxima] (SdkF) {Summe der kleinsten Fehlerquadrate....};    \path [line] (Maxima.east) -- (SdkF);
}
     \only<1-4>{  
     \node [block3, right =of  SdkF] (BSpline) {\textit{B-Spline Approximation}};    \path [line] (SdkF.east) -- (BSpline);
}
       \only<1-5>{
       \node [block2, below =of Messdaten] (Phasenv) {Elimination};       \path [line] (BSpline.south) -- ++(0,-5.5pt) -| (Phasenv);
}
    \only<1-6>{
    \node [block1, right =of  Phasenv] (Aufsp) {Unterteilung ..};    \path [line] (Phasenv.east) -- (Aufsp);
}
          \only<1-7>{
          \node [block1, right =of  Aufsp] (Minima) {Suche ..};          \path [line] (Aufsp.east) -- (Minima);
}
     \only<1-8>{
     \node [block, right =of  Minima] (Rissschl) {\textbf{Ende..}};     \path [line] (Minima.east) -- (Rissschl);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, you should move all the \usetikzlibrary and \tikzset after usepackage{tikz}.

Comment: As @vipa said: `\usepackage{tikz}` first, then load the libraries. Repeated loading of libraries won't break things but it certainly doesn't help either. `\tikzstyle` still works, too, but it is [deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/16595). What's left then is that you're missing the `positioning` library.

Answer (score 0):

You have load the `positioning` library in order to use the `=of` syntax

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
    % Define block styles
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}% für Ellipse
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    pfeil/.style={stealth-},
    beschr/.style={remember picture,overlay,font=\small}}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes}
\tikzset{
  block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, text width=3cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.1cm},
  block1/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=gray!10, text width=3.2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.1cm},
  block2/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=gray!20, text width=3.2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.1cm},
  block3/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=gray!25, text width=3.4cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.1cm},
  line/.style={draw, -latex'}
}
\centering
{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.4cm, auto]
\footnotesize
    % Place nodes
    \only<1>{
    \node [block] (Messdaten) {\textbf{Start:  ..}};
}
    \only<1-2>{
    \node [block1, right =of  Messdaten] (Maxima) {Unterteilung...};        \path [line] (Messdaten.east) -- (Maxima);
}
    \only<1-3>{
    \node [block2, right =of  Maxima] (SdkF) {Summe der kleinsten Fehlerquadrate....};    \path [line] (Maxima.east) -- (SdkF);
}
     \only<1-4>{  
     \node [block3, right =of  SdkF] (BSpline) {\textit{B-Spline Approximation}};    \path [line] (SdkF.east) -- (BSpline);
}
       \only<1-5>{
       \node [block2, below =of Messdaten] (Phasenv) {Elimination};       \path [line] (BSpline.south) -- ++(0,-5.5pt) -| (Phasenv);
}
    \only<1-6>{
    \node [block1, right =of  Phasenv] (Aufsp) {Unterteilung ..};    \path [line] (Phasenv.east) -- (Aufsp);
}
          \only<1-7>{
          \node [block1, right =of  Aufsp] (Minima) {Suche ..};          \path [line] (Aufsp.east) -- (Minima);
}
     \only<1-8>{
     \node [block, right =of  Minima] (Rissschl) {\textbf{Ende..}};     \path [line] (Minima.east) -- (Rissschl);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```